# I don't have the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7; which partition can I delete?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have a Lenovo Ideapad running Windows 7 and I want to install Ubuntu on it. I already installed Ubuntu on a desktop machine using a boot dvd. When I run the installation process on my laptop I don't see the option **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7**.

I understand it's because I already have 4 primary partitions. The question is: can I delete one of those without losing data so I can dual boot?

Comment: Yes you can use any partition to use install Ubuntu. I recommend you to boot from Ubuntu CD/DVD and chose `Try Ubuntu`. Then you can use `Gparted` S/W to make partition. You have to delete any primary partition and create 'Extended` one. Using `Gparted` is as easy as pie. Find out at this link how to use: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html *(**Mod note from jokerdino**: Gparted can destroy data if not handled properly. Proceed with caution.)*

Comment: WARNING: "easy as pie" may be true but it is a tool with which you **can** destroy data!

Comment: @guntbert how do I find out which partition can be deleted? Better yet, what's the best way to familiarise myself with I can and can't do?

Comment: As a first step: Boot to a live CD, there you start the *Disks* utility and create a screenshot about the configuration of your HD. Then post that screenshot into your question (see http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6797/how-do-you-upload-a-screenshot)

Comment: @guntbert I'll do that wednesday, because I don't have my laptop u til then

Answer (score 1):

Note that **deleting a partition will delete all data on that partition**. So first of all, copy your files on the last partition to other partitions.

Then when installing Ubuntu, choose **Something Else** and select that last partition for Ubuntu. Format it to `ext4`, and select the `/` mount point.